# Wildcard silent redirect to a get param

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

So I'm trying to make every user one my website have a subdomain

Whenever a user connects to a wildcard subdomain it ridercts the user to `domain.com/send.php?username='subdomain'`, but I would like to hide the redirect as it appears `subdomain.domain.com` for the user

I'm modifying directly on Apache Virtual Host, and here are my conditions

> RewriteEngine on 
>   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com 
>   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent] 
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www). [NC] 
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).(.*).com [NC] 
>   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%2.com/send.php?username=%1 [NC,L] 
>
>
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC] 
>   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

If I use [P] flag I get a 403 error and if I use an L flag even without R, it shows the redirected URL.

I'm trying to get things through, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your rules. Spome of the matching patterns will never match, please read a bit more about regular expressions. And the overall logic appears reverse in parts, you want to think this through again.

Here is an alternative approach that should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on

# unconditionally redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]

# redirect argument "username=xxx" to the "subdomain"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)username=([a-z][a-z0-9-]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301]

# internally rewrite "subdomain" requests and specify the user name as argument
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(www)\.)?([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?username=%1 [QSA,END]
```

I have not tested this, just wrote it down, so let's hope there is no trivial typo in it :-)

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I tried it out but it doesn't work for me, the only part that works is the http to https. All other wildcard subdomains remain the same and redirect to main domain as in the DNS record. Plus will there be an error if I added a file before the param `username=xxx` like this `send.php?username=xxx`. How will the condition be if so?

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean by "All other wildcard subdomains remain the same and redirect to main domain as in the DNS record"... Now do they "remain the same" or do they redirect? And what does a DNS record have to do with that?

Comment: Also I fail to understand the idea behind that `send.php` script. What does it do? The name suggests it sends the username and I would expect that it then forwards the client to the user name based "subdomain". But for that you don't need a script, that can be done on protocol level as I demonstrated. Looks like you need to revise your question to add more details and much more precision as to what it actually is you want to do...

Comment: Well I created a wildcard DNS record to redirect all subdomains `*.domain.com` to `domain.com`. I'm not really good as I'm new to virtualhosts rules and I'm trying to get by so excuse me for not explaining myself correctly. I'm trying to make a script where you can send a message to a use through `domain.com/send.php?username=xxx` where username is the user you are sending the message to. I'm trying to make the rules to make every user have a subdomain, I would like the URL to stay the same as entered `xxx.domain.com` while it silently redirects the user to `send.php?username=xxx`

Comment: You cannot make a redirection by means of a DNS entry. DNS only resolves host names to IP addresses. Your wildcard entry resolves all hostnames inside the domain "example.com" to the same IP address, but the requests are _still_ targeting the same host name. It is up the the http server to handle that. That is what the virtual hosts are for.

Comment: Please learn the difference between "redirect" and "rewrite", that is important. I suggest you start by reading the documentation of the tool you are using. It is of excellent quality (as typical for OpenSource software) and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I now understand what that script `send.php` is meant to do. You don't actually need the argument "username=XXX" for that. Which simplyfies things quite a lot: you can leave out the middle part of my suggestion. You can instead get the user name from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` inside php.

Comment: I made a slight change and replaced `SERVER_NAME` by `HTTP_HOST`. Sorry for that.